# Upload file to Wep App from browser with out a storage account key

Tags: asp.net, azure, file-upload, azure-blob-storage

Cleary I don't want to give out the Azure Storage account key

How can I load a local file to a BLOB storage without the Azure Storage account key from a browser?
Or can it even be done?

I get from a thick .NET client can do it with SAS.

[Azure File storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/)

> We currently do not support AD-based authentication or ACLs, but do
>   have it in our list of feature requests. For now, the Azure Storage
>   account keys are used to provide authentication to the file share.

This wants a path
[FileUpload Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs 
{
    // Specify the path on the server to
    // save the uploaded file to.
    String savePath = @"c:\temp\uploads\";

// Before attempting to perform operations
// on the file, verify that the FileUpload 
// control contains a file.
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
  // Get the name of the file to upload.
  String fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;

  // Append the name of the file to upload to the path.
  savePath += fileName;


  // Call the SaveAs method to save the 
  // uploaded file to the specified path.
  // This example does not perform all
  // the necessary error checking.               
  // If a file with the same name
  // already exists in the specified path,  
  // the uploaded file overwrites it.
  FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath);
```

I don't see how you could use a SAS as an upload end point.
I don't see anyway in ASP.NET way to upload a file to a blob.

Comment: Do you wish to upload to blob storage or file storage? For uploading to blob storage directly, please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19935404/upload-largefile-to-azure-blob-using-javascript/19935777#19935777.

Answer (score 1):

Some differences between Azure Blob Storage and Azure File Storage are as follows:

- Blob Storage could store unstructured object data (e.g. text or binary data, such as a document, media file).
- File Storage offers shared storage for legacy applications using the standard SMB protocol. Azure File Service is targeted to internal file handling which means that you could mount a file share to a VM in the cloud or on-premises. Azure VM could share files across applications via mounted shares, and on-premises applications could access files via the File service REST API.

For more details, I recommend you reading the following tutorials:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service/

**SAS:** It's a ideal approach to grant the limited access to resources in your storage account to other clients, without having to expose your account key. For more details, you could refer to [Using Shared Access Signatures (SAS)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/).

According to your requirement, I assumed that you could use Blob Storage to store your files. Please follow the steps below to achieve your purpose:

**Generate a SAS URL on a Container**

For a simple way, you could use [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) to create a SAS. For more details, you could follow this [turtorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer/).

**Note**: You need to create a SAS with Write permission on the blob container which is used to store the uploaded files.

**UploadFile.aspx.cs**

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string containerSasUrl = "https://brucechen.blob.core.windows.net/blob-container-01?st=2016-09-21T01%3A59%3A00Z&se=2016-10-01T01%3A59%3A00Z&sp=rw&sv=2015-04-05&sr=c&sig=xGbgBMypxKP%2FBXAHFuzv%2FabqZqjM3W89JYjgf5uvdHo%3D";
        try
        {
            string uploadedFileUrl = string.Empty;
            var file = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
            string blobName = FileUpload1.FileName;
            //Retrieve a reference to a container.
            CloudBlobContainer container = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(containerSasUrl));
            //Retrieve reference to a blob named "blobName".
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
            blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(file.InputStream);
            //Retrieve the uploaded file(blob) url
            uploadedFileUrl = blockBlob.Uri.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO:log
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, you could manage your blob(file) resources and provide public or the specify desired access level to others. For a better understanding of it, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vs-azure-tools-storage-explorer-blobs/).

Comment: Nice.  Have yet tested to give it a check.  This should be on the Azure Storage Team Blog