# What is the best way to upload 3+ GB files to Azure Blob Storage from ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

Is there a good open source project out there demo-ing LARGE Azure Blob Uploads from ASP.Net MVC? There is a great desktop client called StorageExplorer, but I would like to look at an open source project built for the web, with ASP.Net MVC. Does anybody know of one?

http://storageexplorer.com/
https://github.com/Azure/deco/releases

Comment: Do take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19935404/upload-largefile-to-azure-blob-using-javascript. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using best practices to upload large files to Azure.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Azure-Storage-Build-2014-469cb955